# ". setenv" error after cloning from Github: OMNeT++6.0pre10/11 repo

Tags: omnet++

Context: I am currently working on a research project to run an end to end simulation of a 5G cellular network with simu5G. I need help with the installation of Omnet++6.0pre10(or pre 11) from the command line (I don't have access to a gui).  My operating system is Ubutnu 18.04.5 LTS

I am new to Omnet++ and need help with installation of Omnet++6.0pre10 (or pre11) from the command line.

I have tried looking at the manual, but the latest version is always the 5.6.1 version:
https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/UserGuide.pdf

and the steps I have taken are:

1. forking from the Omnetpp github repository
2. cloning the forked repository to the local machine

But when I try the first step of  `. setenv` it gives me the following error:

> Error: '$dir' does not look like an OMNeT++ root directory

which is the error associated with if the directory is really  pointing to an omnet++ installation dir (if you look at the bash code in setenv file)

Please help in:

1. Advise on how to fix this error with the setenv script
2. how to actually install omnet++6.0pre10(or 11) through the command line and how that differs to the latest user guide (user guide 5.6.1)

Best wishes and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten creating `configure.user` mentioned in [Instalation description](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp#installation), i.e.:

```
cd omnetpp
cp configure.user.dist configure.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the master version of OMNeT++ is not the best choice, especially if you are doing research. I would advise to use instead the omnetpp-X.y-src-core.tgz version which does not have the IDE. However also the `omnetpp-x.y-src-linux.tgz` version would do fine as long as you disable the OSG, OSG_EARTH and QTENV components in `configure.user`, before running `./configure`